# Convert multiple xlsm files automatically to multiple csv files by using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have 300 raw datas (.xlsm) and wanne to extract useful datas and turn them to csv files as input for subsequent neural network, now  i try to implement them with 10 datas as example, i have sucessfully extracted the informations what i need, but i dont know how to convert them to csv files with the same name, for single data we can use df.to_csv, but how about for all the datas? with for function?

```
    import glob
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    import csv
    import os

    excel_files = glob.glob('../../Versuch/Versuche/RohBeispiel/*.xlsm') 
    directory = '/Beispiel'
    for files in excel_files:
        data = pd.read_excel(files)
        # getting the list of rows and columns you need
        list_of_dfs = pd.DataFrame(data.values[0:600:,12:26], 
                                   columns=data.columns[12:26]).drop(['Sauberkeit', 'Temparatur'], axis=1)
        # converting pandas dataframe columns to numeric: string into float
        cols = ['KonzA', 'KonzB', 'KonzC', 'TempA', 
                'TempB', 'TempC', 'Modul1', 'Modul2', 
                'Modul3', 'Modul4', 'Modul5', 'Modul6']
        list_of_dfs[cols] = list_of_dfs[cols].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce', axis=1)
        # Filling down from a column through missing data
        for fec in list_of_dfs[cols]:
            list_of_dfs[fec].fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)       

        csvfilename = files.split('/')[-1].split('.')[0] + '.csv'
        newtempfile = os.path.join(directory,csvfilename)
        print(newtempfile)
        print(list_of_dfs.head(2))
```

problem is solved.

```
folder_name = 'Beispiel'
csvfilename = files.split('/')[-1].split('.')[0] + '.csv'  # change into csv files
newtempfile = os.path.join(folder_name, csvfilename)

# Verify if directory exists
if not os.path.exists(folder_name):
    os.makedirs(folder_name)  # If not, create it

print(newtempfile)
list_of_dfs.to_csv(newtempfile, index=False)
```

Comment: From `excel_files`, you can get the filename as `os.path.basename(file)`. You just need to iterate through this list as well when writing the csv

Comment: thx, it helps to save with the same name, but i have only saved the last file and i want to save them in another folder. whats your mean to iterate through this list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way of doing this is to get the filename from the excel and then use the os.path.join() method to save it to the directory you want.

```
directory = "C:/Test"
for files in excel_files:
    csvfilename = (os.path.basename(file)[-1]).replace('.xlsm','.csv') 
    newtempfile=os.path.join(directory,csvfilename)
```

Since you already have the excel df you want to push into the csv file, just add the above code to the loop and change the output csv file to 'newtempfile' and that should do it.

```
df.to_csv(newtempfile, 'Beispel/data{0}.csv'.format(idx))
```

Hope this helps. :)

## Updated Code:

```
    cols = ['KonzA', 'KonzB', 'KonzC', 'TempA', 
                    'TempB', 'TempC', 'Modul1', 'Modul2', 
                        'Modul3', 'Modul4', 'Modul5', 'Modul6']
    excel_files = glob.glob('../../Versuch/Versuche/RohBeispiel/*.xlsm')
        for file in excel_files:
            data = pd.read_excel(file, columns = cols) # import only the columns you need to the dataframe
            csvfilename = (os.path.basename(files)[-1]).replace('.xlsm','.csv') 
            newtempfile=os.path.join(directory,csvfilename)
            
            # converting pandas dataframe columns to numeric: string into float
            data[cols] = data[cols].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce', axis=1)
            data[cols].fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)
            data.to_csv(newtempfile).format(idx)
```

Comment: the code above works well, but with ''df.to_csv(newtempfile, 'Beispel/data{0}.csv'.format(idx))'' it has error: "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'to_csv'

Comment: This would mean that the df you've created is not a valid pandas dataframe.
You might want to include that in the original for loop and not another one & process each file one at a time instead of creating a list of dataframes.

Comment: I can see that you have imported excel to df called 'data' and not 'df'.

I have updated the answer with possible correct code. Let me know if it works.

Comment: with your updated code i can't get the useful information what i need, it looks the same as raw data, this code: "list_of_dfs = pd.DataFrame(data.values[0:600:,12:26],columns=data.columns[12:26]).drop(['Sauberkeit', 'Temparatur'], axis=1)"  is to extract the useful informations.

Comment: You can use this code to get the required information by placing it anywhere after the excel import line. I hope you're experimenting with the code and trying to understand how to apply it to your case.

Comment: thanks very much, i have found the Problem due to the wrong dictionary

Comment: Glad to hear that. If my code was helpful, you can upvote/ accept is as an answer. Cheers!

Comment: how can it upvoat or accept? sorry, i am totally new here